# Cannot remove attributes in ldap with spring ldap

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-ldap

we need to make a spring boot project that works with spring ldap.
every things is good.But when we remove a member from a group,the member deleted form group (i see it in debug mode in a Setmembers) but, in ldap(Oracle Internet Directory) that member exists! 
Please help me!

```
//Group Entry
@Entry(objectClasses = {"top", "groupOfUniqueNames", "orclGroup"}, base = "cn=Groups")
public final class Group {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    private String name;


    private String description;

    private String displayName;

    @Attribute(name = "ou")
    private String ou;

    @Attribute(name = "uniqueMember")
    private Set<Name> members;


    public void addMember(Name newMember) {
        members.add(newMember);
    }

    public void removeMember(Name member) {
        members.remove(member);
    }


//Custom LdapUtils 
public class CustomLdapUtils {

private static final String GROUP_BASE_DN = "cn=Groups";

    private static final String USER_BASE_DN = "cn=Users";

    public Name buildGroupDn(String name) {
        return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(GROUP_BASE_DN)
                .add("cn","Charts")
                .add("cn",name)
                .build();
    }

    private static final CsutomLdapUtils LDAP_UTILS = new CsutomLdapUtils ();
    private CsutomLdapUtils () {
    }
    public Name buildPersonDn(String name) {
        return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(USER_BASE_DN)
                .add("cn", name)
                .build();
    }
}

//Controller
 @DeleteMapping(value = "/memberOfGroup", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> removeMemberFromGroup(@RequestBody Map<String,String> map) throws NamingException {
        List<Group> groupToFind = ldapSearchGroupsService.getGroupByCn(map.get("groupName"));

        List<User> userToFind = ldapSearchUserService.getAllUserByUserName(map.get("userName"));
        if (groupToFind.isEmpty()) {
            //TODO : Group no found!
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            for (Group group1 : groupToFind) {
                group1.removeMember(userToFind.stream().findAny().get().getDn());
                //ldapBindGroupService.deleteMemberFromGroup(group1);
                DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(CustomLdapUtils.getInstance().buildGroupDn(map.get("groupName")));
                ctx.removeAttributeValue("uniqueMember",map.get("userName"));
                ctx.rebind(CustomLdapUtils.getInstance().buildGroupDn(map.get("groupName")),map.get("groupName"));
                ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Is some problem in code? or need some methods?

Comment: Please fix the grammar in your post. Some parts are not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after several search and debug,i found the problem!
In each ldap env,after every changes,the directory must be commit and apply.
In above code,i implemented that,but not in true way!
Best way is here:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/membersOfGroup", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> removeMemberFromGroup(@RequestBody Map<String,String> map) {
        List<Group> groupToFind = ldapSearchGroupsService.getGroupByCn(map.get("groupName"));
        List<User> userToFind = ldapSearchUserService.getAllUserByUserName(map.get("userName"));
        if (groupToFind.isEmpty()) {
            //TODO : Group no found!
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            for (Group group1 : groupToFind) {
                group1.removeMember(userToFind.stream().findAny().get().getDn());
                DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(CustomLdapUtils.getInstance().buildGroupDn(map.get("groupName")));
                ctx.removeAttributeValue("member",CustomLdapUtils.getInstance().buildPersonDn(map.get("userName")));

//True way
                ldapTemplate.update(group1);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```